# How to obtain a point that is nearest to other points?

Tags: algorithm, math

Here is the question that I meet.

[image: formulation]

Intuitively speaking, I want to obtain a point z that is nearest to all other points f_j, but, when the distance between f_j and z is less than m_j, the loss can be omitted.

I cannot solve this problem with a closed form solution, but I can get the optimal solution by enumerating all possible cases through fixing whether the point z is in the circle of f_j or not.

I want to know that if there are any methods that I can use to tackle this problem?

Comment: This is not really a programming problem. A math stackexchange should be a better fit for this question.

Comment: Maybe a conjugate gradient approach?

Comment: The problem is non-convex, so while any gradient descent method might work reasonably well in practice, there is no guarantee that it would find the optimum. This really depends on the size of `m` and the distribution of nearest-neighbour distances, in particular at the lower end. If `m` is large compared to -- let's say -- the 5th percentile of the nearest neighbor distances then a gradient descent approach will need some serious augmentation with multiple restarts, simulated annealing, etc.

Comment: Question: why is there a finite number of solutions? Does your data have a finite granularity? Are there a finite number of places that you can place your center? This would substantially reduce the scope of the problem.

Comment: @Paul Are you sure? I would say the problem is perfectly convex, making gradient methods a good fit. Btw, I believe the finite possibilities are meant with respect to the max function. For every point, you have either the left or the right term in the max, so you have 2^n possible solutions. For every solution, you then need to check if you chose the correct term. Otherwise, it is invalid.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The problem is not convex. Image 3 points on a line A, B, C. Let d(A, B) - m - epsilon = d(B, C), i.e. B is nearly the midpoint between A and C but off by m and little bit. Then there are two minima with equal cost -- unless I am mistaken (my brain is fried by the summer heat today).

Comment: @Paul: I can't really follow your reasoning. Convex functions are allowed to have plateaus if this is what you mean. Here is my reasoning of why the function *is* convex: f(z)=0 is obviously convex. g(z)=(z-x)^2-c is a quadratic function with positive quadratic coefficients and therefore also convex. max(f(x), g(x)) is convex since both f(x) and g(x) are convex. And the sum of convex functions is also convex. Hence, the total function is convex. It is however not strictly convex due to the clamping.

Comment: Thank you all. I will try some optimizer to tackle this problem, since my data is not very large.

Comment: @NicoSchertler You are right, of course. What I thought are two minima are really just the boundaries of a plateau.